# How to open file from vim in case insensitive manner

Tags: vim

Lets say you have a file `ExAMplE.java` in your current directory and you are editing some other file in the same directory using vim. I would open a file from vim using `:e fileName` but since the name of this file is all crappy , is there a way to make vim edit command suggest you the name of file `ExAMple.java` if you just type `exam<tab>` .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
set wildignorecase
```

See `:h 'wildignorecase'`.

Comment: In case it helps someone: In my case (opposite of asker: I had case-insensitive, but wanted case-sensitive search), I tried `set nowildignorecase` but saw no effect -- looked at `:h 'wildignorecase'` and found out that what I needed was `set nofileignorecase` (see `:h 'fileignorecase'`).

Comment: In case it helps someone: beware that `set ignorecase` is for ignoring case in search patterns (only). You may then need both `ignorecase` and `wildignorecase` if you want to be case insensitive both in patterns AND file completions.